# React router doesn't refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest, axios, react-router

I have two different routes that are using the same component.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>  
        <Route path="/produktai" element={<Products />}/>
        <Route path="/produktai/:productId" element={<Products />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I'm using Link from react to switch between pages and get id's from

```
    const pathname = useLocation().pathname;
```

to perform rest api's.

For example, when i change pages using Link from /products to /products/2, url changes but the problem is that page doesn't refresh as it should. Problem solves if i'm using a tag with href as it always reloads page unlike smooth react Link functionality but i don't think that's a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the route path changes you are still rendering the same `Products` component. If you need to run some logic when the path changes, or more likely, when the `productId` route param updates, then you should use an `useEffect` hook with the `productId` route param as a dependency.

Example:

```
const { productId } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  if (productId) {
    // Perform rest api call and response handling
  }
}, [productId]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better approach for this issue. Give unique keys like below.

```
    <Route path="/all-reports">
        <ReportsPage key="1" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/shared-reports">
        <ReportsPage key="2" mode="shared" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/owned-reports">
        <ReportsPage key="3" mode="owned" />
    </Route>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised it worked! Adding keys seems to be the solution to a lot of React issues, hahaha