# React router refresh element on location change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My question is very similar to one here, but this solution didn't work for me.
[React router doesn't refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541992/react-router-doesnt-refresh-page/71552116)

My default app has a router (I'm using react router v6) I have a series of blog posts which I want to use the same code but appear with a different URL and load data from the same API. It makes sense to use the same blog() function to build these so the router points to the same element.

```
import { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useParams, useNavigate, useSearchParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
return (
<Header Title={"My blog"}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="blog1" element={<Blog />} />
    <Route path="blog2" element={<Blog />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
  </Routes>
  </Header>
  );
}
```

with the blog function similar to the below:

```
function Blog() {
  console.log(`blog re ran`);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const location = useLocation();
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  var loaded = false;
  let routerpath = location.pathname;
  let routerpath2 = routerpath.substring(1);
  const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))
  async function load () { 
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log(`Refresh timer: ${i}`);
    await timer(120000); // then the created Promise can be awaited
    setCount(0);
    console.log("Count reset.");
    loaded = false;
    }
  }
useEffect(() => {
    if (routerpath) {
    if (count == 0) {
      fetch(`https://api.example.com/api.php?route=${routerpath2}`)
        .then((Response) => {
          if (Response.ok) {
            return Response.json();
          }
          throw Response;
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setData(data);
          console.log("API call answered. {productId}");
          loaded = false;
          setCount(count + 1);
          console.log("Count incremented.");
load(); 
        })
    }, [data, count, location, location.pathname, routerpath ]);
 if (data) {
    if (loaded == false){
          console.log("Reloaded content.");
    return (
    <div>
{data.BlogPosts.map((BlogPost, i) => {
 return (
<Typography paragraph>{BlogPost.MainContent}</Typography>
);
}
</div>
  );
  load(); 
  loaded = true;
}
}
```

I had to add the count constant and loaded var to stop the app from continuously querying the API, I have another function not included here which puts in a wait of 2 minutes before refreshing. I think its the use of the wait function and the count/loaded vars that stop the content changing on change of the page. I've tried adding location based dependencies to the useEffect, and adding a refresh at the start of the blog function, in the console output I can see the 'blog re ran' message multiple times so know that this code is re-run I don't understand why the api call isn't made .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using, or don't want to use, a dynamic route path such as `<Route path="/:blogId" element={<Blog />} />` where the `Blog` component  would then just use `const { blogId } = useParams()` and make the appropriate fetch request. This would be the solution similar to the other SO post you linked to.

If you want to use two separate routes like you have then I'd suggest just passing in the `route` queryString value as a prop. When the `route` prop changes it will trigger the `useEffect` hook to refetch blog posts based on the current `route` dependency value.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="blog1" element={<Blog route="blog1" />} />
  <Route path="blog2" element={<Blog route="blog2" />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Blog

```
function Blog({ route }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.example.com/api.php?route=${route}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // catch/handle any rejected Promises or thrown errors
      });
  }, [route]);

  return data?.BlogPosts?.length
    ? data.BlogPosts.map((post, i) => (
      <Typography key={post.id} paragraph>
        {post.MainContent}
      </Typography>
    ))
    : null;
}
```