# Is there any way to re-render or reload my page with different parameters while changing the parameters from the component in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my App.js file where the routes are being defined.

```
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} exact element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path={"/charts/:id"} exact element={<ChartsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

This is the code for the Charts Component in which the param is getting updated and the API is being fetched accordingly.

```
    import {useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router";
    import {useQuery} from "react-query";
    import axios from "axios";
    import countryCode from "...";

    export default function ChartsPage(){
      let params = useParams();
      let navigate = useNavigate();

      useEffect(() => {
        getChartsByCountry.params.country_code = params?.id;
      }, [params?.id]);

      const { data: chartsDataBycountry } = useQuery(
        ["countryCharts", params?.id],
        () => axios(getChartsByCountry),
        { refetchOnWindowFocus: false, enabled: !!params?.id }
      );

      return(
       <div className="chartsPage-container">
          <div className="country-selector">
              <select className="country--options__items">
                 {countryCode.map((country, index) => (
                    <option
                      onClick={() => console.log(country.code)}
                      key={index}
                      value={country.code}
                      className="country--options__item"
                    >
                      {country.country}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
      )
    }
```

countryCode is an array of objects which looks like this -

```
const countryCode = [
  { code: "", country: "Global" },
  { code: "DZ", country: "Algeria" },
  { code: "AR", country: "Argentina" },
  { code: "AU", country: "Australia" },
  { code: "AT", country: "Austria" },
]
```

Now what I am trying to do is when I am clicking on the **option** tag the params of the URL should change so that the required API is being fetched accordingly.
Should I update the *getChartsByCountry.params.country_code* and then re-render or reload the page or is there any way to update the params of the URL directly. Or if there's any other way altogether to do it, please let me know.
I hope I am making sense now.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "need to change the params in the url through my component" and what "workaround" you are trying to accomplish. This likely includes editing the post to include a [mcve] of the relavent code you are working with and have an issue using. Do you mean there is some `Chart` component rendered on *some* `"/charts/:countryCode"` path and it needs to "react" to the `countryCode` path parameter changing?

Comment: Yes, I exactly mean that. Sorry if I wasn't able to clarify with what I meant.

Comment: Can you share your routes declaration and this relevant component code, i.e. the chart component, that is using the route path param, and how the route params are changed, so we may see what it's doing? See [mcve].

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71552116/8690857

Comment: I have edited my question, if you are able to understand it then please help me with the work around.

Comment: What is `getChartsByCountry` and why are you directly mutating it?

Comment: I am using it to call an API   `export const getChartsByCountry = {
  method: "get",
  url: "https://shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com/v1/charts/country",
  params: { country_code: "" },
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "...",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com",
  },
};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly accessing the `params.id` value when the route changes and the `id` path param will have an updated value in the `ChartsPage` component. I think the issue here is one of object mutation. It appears that the `getChartsByCountry` object is mutated in the `useEffect` hook.

I suspect you might just need to shallow copy the `getChartsByCountry` object in the `useQuery` hook directly and override the `country_code` property.

Example:

```
const { id } = useParams();

const { data: chartsDataBycountry } = useQuery(
  ["countryCharts", id],
  () => axios({
    ...getChartsByCountry,
    params: {
      ...getChartsByCountry.params,
      country_code: id,
    },
  }),
  { refetchOnWindowFocus: false, enabled: !!id }
);
```

Comment: I had no idea you can do something like this, I have been calling all the APIs in my previous projects like before. Thanks a ton for this. Just one more question, how to change the value of `id` when clicking on the `option` tag?

Comment: @RayyanAlam Looks like you could use the click handler and do something like ```onClick={() => navigate(`../${country.code}`)}```, or possibly attach an `onChange` handler to the `select` input and do something like ```onChange={e => navigate(`../${e.target.value}`)}```, this will issue a navigation action and update the URL and rerender the route/component.